# Graph Connectivity

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am given an initial connected graph $G$ with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges. At each step I remove an edge from $G$ and ask if $G$ is connected. Can the queries be answered in $\mathcal{O}(\log n)$ time using some preprocessing or techniques?

Comment: Any chance that you can assume that your graph is planar?

Comment: Also, is your graph directed or undirected?

Comment: Of course during preprocessing you could generate a hashmap of all possible subgraphs that might occur . In this way the queries could be answered even in $O(1)$ but I bet that is not what you want ... so I think there are missing some details in your question?

Comment: In other words: I bet there are some restriction for preprocessing time, needed memory, ...

Comment: Such a collection would be exponential in size, which would require linear time to search.  There is not known to be any device in the universe which can store $n$ bits of data and look them up in faster than $O(log n)$ time.

Comment: You might also want to try asking this question at the computer science stack exchange cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2133147) (I'm not sure if there is a free version of this).